# Как изменить значение внутри созданного объекта?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
 showSlider = noUiSlider.create(slider, {
                                start: [0, 100],
                                connect: true,
                                step: 1,
                                range: {
                                'min': 0,
                                'max': 100
                                }
                        });
```

Собственно создается объект, потом я с помощью ajax запрашиваю значения. У [библиотеки](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) есть функция изменения значения массива `start`, но не нашел  функции изменения `range`. Как можно с помощью jquery изменить это значение или пересоздать объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странное решение вы нашли, когда есть правильное. Источник — https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-update

```
slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
    range: {
        'min': 500,
        'max': 1000
    }
});
```

Comment: Ну как бы не странное оба рабочих, но ваше более рациональное сударь :)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение в документации по плагину

```
slider.noUiSlider.destroy()
```

И потом пересоздать